# Select different values, which are not included in a column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

## Help

Determine number of routes which are served by the greatest number of flights

1. A – B and B – A are to be considered the same route
2. Use only trip table

My Table Trip cointains (trip_no, id_comp, plane, town_from, town_to, time_out, time_in)

I have this Query, but i need to select different values, which are not included in a column of the same table.

```
SELECT COUNT(trip_no) AS NumFlights,town_from,town_to 
FROM   trip
GROUP  BY town_from, 
          town_to 
ORDER  BY numflights DESC;
```

and this is my result set

```
NumFlights, town_from, town_to
'4', 'Moscow', 'Rostov'
'4', 'London', 'Singapore'
'4', 'Rostov', 'Moscow'
'4', 'Singapore', 'London'
'1', 'Paris', 'Rostov'
'1', 'Paris', 'London'
'1', 'Vladivostok', 'Rostov'
'1', 'Rostov', 'Paris'
'1', 'London', 'Paris'
'1', 'Rostov', 'Vladivostok'
```

Comment: You have to provide both Data Sample and Desire Output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: what is the problem? Do you want eliminate duplicate routes? Show only `A->B` and remove `B->A` ??

Comment: I need yo skip the values, Paris to Rostov is the same Route than Rostov to Paris i need to group this, I dont know how to do this D:

Comment: dont post your result as comment, just update the question

Comment: I dont know how to explain me T_T sorry

Comment: That is why I provide the links, so you read and learn how to ask better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do what you want using `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(trip_no) AS NumFlights,
       LEAST(town_from, town_to) as town_1, 
       GREATEST(town_from, town_to) as town_2
FROM trip
GROUP BY LEAST(town_from, town_to), 
         GREATEST(town_from, town_to)
ORDER BY numflights DESC;
```

Comment: I also have this solution, but not sure if OP want `'8', 'Moscow', 'Rostov'`

Comment: Oh thank you so much :D i dont know a lot of sql :D, i dont know this function :D Least and Greatest :D thank you a lot

Comment: Yes this solution is that i wanted :D